# How to find the work/application related to a paper?

Tags: phd, research-process, citations, thesis

I am doing my PhD research on AI. One paper I read was very interesting for my research, and I feel I should compare my result with theirs.

Datasets we use are different for testing and the only way to make the comparison is by using their application/library with my dataset. Therefore, I need to get the application/library they built in order to use it for comparison.

I searched for their work anywhere online but could not find it. How can I compare my method and theirs in that case? What shall I write in my paper in that case I cannot find their work?

Comment: To get the obvious question out of the way, have you tried contacting the authors of that paper?

Comment: @Anyon yes, there was no answer

Comment: If they didn't publish code with the paper and they don't respond to contact, you're out of luck. You could implement their algorithm based on their written methods.

Comment: Perhaps [How should I proceed if the author of a paper doesn't reply to my query?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13543/17254) could be useful. Also, it is often the case that the authors may be more responsive to emails from your advisor.